# useState setter is never called, and not updating state in useEffect block

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Initially I do an API call in a `useEffect` block, and setting `setLatestTimeStamp` which is a `useState` setter.

The mission is to first fetch initial data (20 minutes f.eks, set the latest date received as latesttimestamp, then useEffect is called due to change, and then... every 5 seconds.. get new data from latesttimestamp until now.

I have `latestTimeStamp` trigger on another `useState` block, which fetches data every 5 second, setting `setLatestTimeStamp` again which re-triggers the `useEffect`.

The `latestTimeStamp` is sat correctly in the first `useEffect`, but it won't fire in the second one.

Do I need to use something else than `useState` on this, or is it something I've missed?

It calls the API every 5 seconds, but the `latestTimeStamp` is *not* updated:

[image]

```js
const Roll: React.FC<RollProps> = ({ selectedTimeSpan }) => {

  const [chart, setChart] = useState<ChartXY | undefined>(undefined);
  const [latestTimeStamp, setLatestTimeStamp] = useState<string>('');

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      
      const timeSpanString:string = selectedTimeSpan === 180 ? '?startTime=2023-09-17T07:05:00&endTime=2023-09-17T09:05:00' : '?startTime=2023-09-17T07:05:00&endTime=2023-09-17T07:25:00'

      try {

    // --> INITIAL FETCH TO GET 20 MINUTES OF DATA <--
        const response = await axios.get(`http://url/api?{timeSpanString}`);
        
        chartData = response.data;

   // --> SET THE LATESTTIMESTAMP TO TRIGGER THE OTHER USEEFFECT.<--
        setLatestTimeStamp(chartData.rollData[chartData.rollData.length - 1].timestamp);

      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Unable to fetch data", error);
      }
      
    }

    fetchData();

  }, [chart, selectedTimeSpan]);

// ****** useEffect for handling interval and adding data ****** //
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
      try {
        console.log('First call on Interval: latestTimeStamp is:', latestTimeStamp);

        const timeSpanString: string = `?startTime=${latestTimeStamp}&endTime=${new Date().toISOString()}`;

    // --> FETCH DATA FROM LATESTTIMESTAMP TO NOW AND APPEND IT TO DATASET (all code is not shown, but not needed for this logic)...
        const response = await axios.get(`http://url/api?${timeSpanString}`);
        const newChartData: RollSet = response.data;

        // PS PS !! THIS CONSOLE.LOG is NEVER CALLED....
        console.log("NEW TIMESTAMP VALUE IS --> ", newChartData.rollData[newChartData.rollData.length - 1].timestamp)
        
    // --> UPDATE LATESTDATESTAMP EACH ROUNDTRIP <--
setLatestTimeStamp(newChartData.rollData[newChartData.rollData.length - 1].timestamp);
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unable to fetch data', error);
      }
    }, 5000);

    // Cleanup interval on component unmount
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [latestTimeStamp]);

}
```

Comment: you explained what's happening but not your precise intention. what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Mulan Sorry.. i have extended my question with more comments now :) More understandable ?

Answer (score 0):

Setting latestTimeStamp inside an effect the is triggered by latestTimeStamp will create a loop as updating the value will trigger the effect again.  This causes the interval to be cleared and a new interval to be set every time.  Instead, try setting the interval inside of your first effect like so:

```
const Roll: React.FC<RollProps> = ({ selectedTimeSpan }) => {

  const [chart, setChart] = useState<ChartXY | undefined>(undefined);
  const [latestTimeStamp, setLatestTimeStamp] = useState<string>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {

      let timeSpanString: string;
      if (!latestTimeStamp) {
        // Get initial time span
        timeSpanString = selectedTimeSpan === 180 ? '?startTime=2023-09-17T07:05:00&endTime=2023-09-17T09:05:00' : '?startTime=2023-09-17T07:05:00&endTime=2023-09-17T07:25:00'
      } else {
        // Get next time span
        timeSpanString = `?startTime=${latestTimeStamp}&endTime=${new Date().toISOString()}`;
      }

      try {

        // --> INITIAL FETCH TO GET 20 MINUTES OF DATA <--
        const response = await axios.get(`http://url/api?{timeSpanString}`);

        chartData = response.data;

        // --> SET THE LATESTTIMESTAMP TO TRIGGER THE OTHER USEEFFECT.<--
        setLatestTimeStamp(chartData.rollData[chartData.rollData.length - 1].timestamp);

      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Unable to fetch data", error);
      }

    }

    fetchData();

    const intervalId = setInterval(fetchData, 5000)

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId)

  }, [chart, selectedTimeSpan]);

}
```